# C++ game loading objects / global objects

Tags: c++, object, load, globalization, extern

I am still new to C++ so please forgive me if my question is unbearably obvious. I am (attempting) to code an RPG game. Everything is compiling nicely at the moment, however I now have to think about how I am going to load all of my objects (for unit classes, items etc) when the game opens.

I have seen threads about DLL's and global objects using extern's in header files, but I wondered which was the most practical/efficient method? (As the game itself will only be so large)

As it stands, my code is very clunky and not well implemented ( I did not even think before trying to use a function to declare my objects in a separate function and wonder why they weren't accessible), should I be using extern rather than having to declare my objects in main() in order to instantiate them (see below).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Unit.h"
#include "UClass.h"

using namespace std;

// Seperate function at program start to load class list.
void loadClass(UClass& obj)
{
    obj.load("Peasant");

}

int main() {

    //Load classes...
    cout << "Creating peasant...\n";
    UClass peasant;
    loadClass(peasant);
    cout << peasant.show() << endl;

    cout << "\nCreating unit...\n";
    Unit man;
    man.SetLvl();
    man.SetClass(peasant);
    man.ShowInfo();

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry again, this is my first attempt at a multiple file project and thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you referring to how to 1) load resource files containing data (textures, dialog, names, ...) used to initialize objects, 2) create actual objects in a way that they are available across different source files (translation units) 3) Something completely different.

Comment: Global variables are generally to be avoided. Your code looks fine to me. Not sure what you think DLLs have to do with anything.

Comment: @Agentlien. I am referring to the first point you wrote about yes. I didn't know whether the way I have initialised my objects was inefficient (Because I would have to do it many times over to include all the objects i need) :/

Comment: @john. I may be misunderstanding, but I meant global objects? ( would they still be called a variable?) As I was not sure wether the objects would only be accessible from the main() function? Or have I misunderstood >.<

Comment: @Iskardes Not sure what distinction you are drawing between global objects and global variables. But the objects you create in main are accessible outside of main, you do it in your loadClass function for instance. The *names* you use in main are only visible in main but that doesn't mean the objects they name are not accessible outside of main. In C++ these issues of what should be accessible where are usually solved by writing classes.

Comment: @john I think I understand what you mean now, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into std library where you have defined such structures as for example list. My idea would be for you to create list of objects that you load to your game, and while in resolving geometry or other logic you want you would iterate through the list. I think this is good for start. If I got your concerns correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of a list, I shall take a look into that.